# Ошибка при вызове другой формы C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Решил сделать лабу для университета, делал уже 1000 раз так, но проблема пришла откуда не ждали. Компилятор решил устроить истерику и выдает ошибку "Это объявление не содержит спецификатор типа" и "Нужна точка с запятой" на строке с F2->Show(); Я не могу найти какую-то банальную ошибку или у меня компилятор сдох? Я уже так делал и не один раз. Забыл что-то? Второй день голову ломаю, спасите...
Код обработки клика по кнопке:

```
private: System::Void GraphButton_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
}
       MyForm^ F2 = gcnew MyForm();
       F2->Show();
};
```

Что не так?

P.S. Создал абсолютно чистый и новый проект с одной формой. Ругается на абсолютно любой код. Даже на ключевое слово this и банальное MessageBox::Show(). А, очевидно, чтобы окончательно меня добить, абсолютно одинаковый код работает в проектах, которые я делал до этого.

Пробовал создать новый проект - все равно генерирует какие-то неадекватные рандомные ошибки. Версия .NET 4.7.2

Comment: Я их только создал, в плане перекрестные ссылки? Я прописал include "Название второй формы.h" в первой. Или этого не надо делать?

Comment: Спасибо за гениальный ответ, но мне нужен с++, это требование лабораторных в институте. Кроме того ошибка явно не в этом, я ради интереса создал пустой проект с пустой формой и 1 кнопкой. В обработчике клика написал стандартный MessageBox::Show(); Тоже ругается. Есть еще идеи с чем это связано? Подозреваю дело в самом VS

Comment: Отлично, вы придрались. Вы прекрасно поняли, что я имел ввиду. Если вы не можете помочь, то не нужно отвечать на вопрос. Спасибо. У меня конкретная проблема, я спросил у местных решения. Но пришли вы и предложили просто сменить язык. Спасибо.

Comment: Очень интересно, что VS ругает даже на ключ. слово this, что нет объявления. Проект полностью пустой и только что созданный. Что за приколы такие?

Comment: Я не предлагал вам просто сменить язык. Я уточнял подробности вашей проблемы. И предлагал решение. То, что вы не описали сразу все нюансы - чья вина?

Comment: Ну, бывает, что-то глюкануло. Перезапустите Студию. Перезагрузите Винду. Возможно, придётся переставлять и то, и другое. | Проект какого типа создаётся? Может, по ошибке кликнут не тот тип проекта?